# Best route for an independent developer to get modern Microsoft source control?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

Given I'm:

- a solo developer using VS2008 Professional
- looking for Microsoft-produced source control (I'm aware there are alternatives)
- looking to get away from Visual SourceSafe 2005

Is it correct that my only option is to drop ~$8k on [Visual Studio Team System 2008 Development Edition](http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/Visual-Studio-Team-System-2008-Development-Edition-with-MSDN-Premium/product/D1B47D75) ($5,469) + [Team Foundation Server](http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/Visual-Studio-Team-System-2008-Team-Foundation-Server/product/55F56593) ($2,799) - in order to get the TFS version control component?

Reading the answers to other related questions it looks like routes to bringing the TFS price down is to either become a Microsoft Gold Certified partner or to take advantage of the ISV Empower program.  I'd welcome any comments related to these options.

The top non-Microsoft solution looks to be [Subversion](http://subversion.net/) + [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/), but I'd really like to go the all-Microsoft route if I can possibly swing it.

The reason that I'd like to go all-Microsoft is that it's my preference to first try the stock solution, and then later try the alternatives with the benefit of that experience. Also, I've had the rare positive experience with SourceSafe. Or, maybe I'm just a closet MS fanboy. :-)

Also, does the picture change at all when VS2010 comes out?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm downloading VisualSVN now to give that a shot since there's no reason not to.

Comment: Ever wish you had a parrot on your shoulder?

Comment: Pure curiosity leads me to ask why you have the desire to go all-Microsoft?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use all-Microsoft stuff or you are just the fan? I had some experience with SourceSafe and it was a horror. SVN is so much easier, and there are others free tools on the market too...

Comment: @ChaosPandion: I don't know if you're making light of my rare birth defect which set my left shoulder 6 inches higer than my right, but it is certainly in poor taste! :-)

Comment: Everyone always seem to be bashing Sourcesafe and while I agree there are more powerfull tools available (I'm using Mercurial too at work and Git at home), we **are** using SourceSafe for 8 years now without any problems. In the near future we plan to upgrade to TFS. *(I feel so relieved coming out:)*

Comment: @Lieven: I've seen a VSS DB going so bad its analyze couldn't repair it -- with the root of the problem being introduced into the DB a week or two before the analyze tool discovered anything at all. This problem alone wasted so much time, the company probably could have financed the whole SVN development team for a few months with the wasted money. And guess what: It took _three such cases within a few months_ until they finally pulled the plug and switched to CVS. (SVN didn't exist back then.) And that's on top of the dreaded nightly analyze run which often discovered minor errors in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are an independent developer, and although I fully understand you wish to go the full-on Microsoft route, I can't stress highly enough that using one over the other won't mean as much to you at this point.

When I started using Source Control, I used VSS... much like many others on this site.  After about 4 months, I quickly realized that there were many issues with it (namely, that it corrupted every 10 days or so, and that it caused my machine to lag horribly.)

I switched over to SVN and I do have to admit, I'm quite happy with the outcome.  When you build your devleopment team to 2,3,4,5... then look into the expense.  You'll find that you can get the same affect of Team Suite if you integrate SVN with something like fogbugz, or look at something like [CodeSpaces](http://www.codespaces.com/)

Answer (score 2):

If you qualify for [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark), that comes with TFS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I should have mentioned that my company is greater than 3 years old, so is not eligble for BizSpark.  Good tip for others who might read this however.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a solo developer you might not need to go the TFS way. As the product name suggests it is for teams. I suggest take a dive into source control systems like Subversion + TortoiseSVN or Mercurial + TortoiseHg. You could even use a web based source control if it fits your needs, sometime like Launchpad.net

Answer (score 0):

If you would say why you are so hip on getting it from Microsoft, we might better be able to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Give SVN a try. Look at TortoiseSVN, AnkhSVN, and Visual SVN.